# Domain of $\sqrt{\sin(\cos x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How we can find the Domain of $\sqrt {\sin(\cos x)}$ ?

My attempt:-

$$ \sin(\cos x)>0 \implies\cos x>0 \implies x>π/2$$

But it is right or wrong ?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y:=\cos(x)$, so we are considering the function $f(x)=\sqrt{\sin(y)}$. The domain of $f$ in terms of $y$ is $\sin(y)\geq 0\iff y\in\cup_{k\in\mathbb Z}[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$. But we know that $|y|\leq 1$, so the domain of $f$ is just $0\leq y\leq 1$. Can you finish this, i.e. what does $0\leq y\leq 1$ translate to in terms of $x$?

Comment: $ y\in\cup_{k\in\mathbb Z}[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$  can you explain this and also what is the U shape symbol means , I never use this

Comment: The $\cup$ symbol means union, so it's taking the collection of all intervals of the form $[2k\pi,(2k+1)\pi]$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$. However, as I say in my answer, it turns out that the restriction on $y$ simply becomes $0\leq y\leq 1$ since we already have $|y|\leq 1$.